# Laravel 5.4 table relationship between 3 small tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a recently started learning Laravel 5.4, I am having trouble with my 3 way table relationship, I've looked at a few articles online regarding many to many, but this relationship is just a "hasOne" on both sides.

Could anyone give me a helpful hint as to how to structure my table relationship, here is the PK/FK relationship:

```
Users table     (id)

Listings table  (id, user_id)

Insights table  (id, listing_id) - one insight row per listing only.
```

And the models below:

**Users Model**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function listing()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Listing');
    }
}
```

**Listing Model**

```
class Listing extends Model
{
    public function insight()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Insight');
    }    
}
```

**Insight Model**

```
class Insight extends Model
{
    public function listing()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Listing');
    }    
}
```

And what I am trying to achieve is to query the users own listings, with each listings current insights.

Thanks a bunch.

Simon.

Comment: You mean, 1 user has 1 listing which has 1 insight?

Comment: Hi @aleksandrs, thanks, the user could have many listings but listings have only one insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function listing()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Listing::class);
    }
}

class Listing extends Model
{
    public function insight()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Insight::class);
    } 

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }    
}

class Insight extends Model
{
    public function listing()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Listing::class);
    }    
}

$users = User::with('listing.insight')->get();

foreach($users as $user) {
    $user->listing->insight;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, amending the relationships and using User::with(['listing.insight'])->find($user_id); worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

User model

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function listing()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Listing');
    }
}
```

Listing Model

```
class Listing extends Model
{
    public function insight()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Insight');
    } 

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }    
}
```

Insight Model

```
class Insight extends Model
{
    public function listing()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Listing');
    }    
}
```

And if you want query users with Listing and Insight

```
$users = User::with(['listing', 'listing.insight'])->get();

foreach($users as $user) {
    $user->listing->insight;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Morteza Rajabi for your help, I am trying to achieve the query you listed, but by user ID, if we assume the user_id is 1, would I be able to include that in the query as well?

Comment: Use 'find($id)' instead if 'get()' fir a user and wont need to foreach

Comment: @MortezaRajabi I think @SimonEl said a user could have many listings. And i think there is no need to query twice here `$users = User::with(['listing', 'listing.insight'])->get();`. You can get what you want using `$users = User::with('listing.insight')->get();`.

Comment: @MortezaRajabi Thanks so much for your help. Ako was right about the many listings, sorry for not been clear enough. Your answer helped me refine the result. [