# Laravel Relationships: hasManyThrough, belongsTo, belongsToMany

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Heyy, I have a Laravel project here, can u guys help me with this question about relationship?

I have the following database structure:

```
users
    id
    name
    email
    password

event
    id
    description
    city_id

block_range
    id
    event_id

user_block_ranges
    user_id
    block_range_id
```

Explanation

`users`: A normal user authentication table. (has a `belongsToMany` relationship with `user_block_ranges`)

`event`: Stores event info. (has a `hasMany` relationship with `block_range`)

`block_range`: Save blocks of time of event. (has a `belongsTo` relationship with `event`)

The real question is: how do I get all the events of the user? Through the `user_block_ranges` then `block_range` relationship? Maybe using `hasManyThrough`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have same as described in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432996/laravel-5-4-table-relationship-between-3-small-tables, only difference, that you will have chain of 4 elements

Comment: @Aleksandrs I can do like this answer even with a ManyToMany table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your models look like this:

**User model**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function blockRanges()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\BlockRange', 'user_block_ranges', 'user_id', 'block_range_id');
    }
}
```

**Block Range model**

```
class BlockRange extends Model
{
    public function event()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Event');
    }
}
```

To get all events of the user you can do this:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

$events = array();

foreach ($user->blockRanges as $block_range) {
    $events = $block_range->event;
}
```

Comment: That worked for me, thank you very much. I really appreciate your answer, but, no way to do this with Laravel ORM? :'(

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found an easy way to do this only with Laravel relationships :(